# Create an array column of key value pairs

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
+---+--------+----+
| Id|    Size| Amt|
+---+--------+----+
| a1|       1|55.0|
| a2|       2|48.0|
| a3|       3|28.0|
+---+--------+----+
```

The schema of this dataframe is:

```
StructType([
      StructField("Id", StringType(), True),
      StructField("Size", IntegerType(), True),
      StructField("Amt", FloatType(), True)
    ])
```

When I use `df.write.json("my_output_path")`, the json file looks like:

```
{"Id":"a1", "Size":1, "Amt":55.0}
{"Id":"a2", "Size":2, "Amt":48.0}
{"Id":"a3", "Size":3, "Amt":28.0}
```

Using `df`, I want to create `df1` such that it has a new array column (`Arr`) which contains key value pairs of the existing columns.

The output file of `df1.write.json("my_new_output_path")` should look like something below:

```
{"Id":"a1", "Size":1, "Amt":55.0, "Arr":[{"Id":"a1","Size":1,"Amt":55.0 }] }
{"Id":"a2", "Size":2, "Amt":48.0, "Arr":[{"Id":"a2","Size":2,"Amt":48.0 }] }
{"Id":"a3", "Size":3, "Amt":28.0, "Arr":[{"Id":"a3","Size":3,"Amt":28.0 }] }
```

I tried the following but it gave me a different output:

```
df1 = df.select('Id', 'Size', 'Amt', array('Id','Size','Amt').alias("Arr"))
df1.write.json("my_new_output_path")
```

Current Output:

```
{"Id":"a1", "Size":1, "Amt":55.0, "Arr":["a1", 1 ,55.0] }
{"Id":"a2", "Size":2, "Amt":48.0, "Arr":["a2", 2 ,48.0] }
{"Id":"a3", "Size":3, "Amt":28.0, "Arr":["a3", 3 ,28.0] }
```

How can I get the expected output? Any solutions or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want key-value pairs, a dictionary would be more suitable, instead of using `array` try `create_map` (`map` in Scala). This function takes a list of columns that are grouped as key-value pairs (key1, value1, key2, value2, ...).

```
df1 = df.select('Id', 'Size', 'Amt', create_map(lit('Id'), 'Id', lit('Size'), 'Size', lit('Amt'), 'Amt').alias("Arr"))
```

`lit` is used here to create columns with literal string values.

Then save the new dataframe as before, the resulting json will look as follows:

```
{"Id":"a1","Size":1,"Amt":55.0,"Arr":{"Id":"a1","Size":"1","Amt":"55.0"}}
{"Id":"a2","Size":2,"Amt":48.0,"Arr":{"Id":"a2","Size":"2","Amt":"48.0"}}
{"Id":"a3","Size":3,"Amt":28.0,"Arr":{"Id":"a3","Size":"3","Amt":"28.0"}}
```